# Python - Angle Between Search Query and Document

Tags: python, math

I've been having a bit of trouble understanding how this works.

If I have multiple documents containing a lot of words each, and a single word that may be contained in the documents, how can I tell what the angle is between the word and these documents?

For instance if docs.txt contains "This world is fake" and queries.txt contains "fake" how do I know what the angle of similarity between them is?

I've found this info: 
"When representing a document as a vector, each vector component represents the number of times the corresponding word in the dictionary appears in the document." and "When representing a search query as a vector, each vector component represents whether the corresponding word in the dictionary appears in the search query (1 if it does and 0 otherwise)."

but I don't really know how I'd make the "fake" string a vector or how to find the angle between it and the docs.txt. I'd like to code this in python but I'm pretty bad at math.

If anyone has any advice that would be awesome, thank you!

Comment: Have you read into tf-idf (term frequency - inverse document frequency)?

Comment: This is abstract Vector spaces with each word counting as a dimension in the vector space - this is maybe not something to tackle if you are "bad at math".

Comment: @rahlf23 I have but I don't really understand it. with the example given, tf would be 1/4 =0.25and if there were 5 documents let's say and that was the only one with "fake" in it, the IDF(t) = log(5/1) so the Tf-idf weight would be ~0.175, right? But I don't really know how that relates to getting an angle.